# Template of Springer Nature’s LaTeX

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, templates, springernature

The template of "Springer Nature’s LaTeX" can be downloaded on:
[Download here](https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support?fbclid=IwAR2d8BVNPx7KFI2OXedReBIQVSrt9b3yo4JN6T_tUFO08aZrpfu-VpNa14o)

However, the bibliographic references do not appear with the bibtex. I ran the zipped version in overleaf.
Can someone help me where I need to change so that I can generate the references using bibtex in this template?

Comment: The `.bst` files in the `bst` folder won't be found by Overleaf. Try uploading the specific `.bst` file you're using to your main folder in your project and see what happens.

Comment: Perfect! Done! Thank you.

Comment: Great, I've turned my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 4):

The `.bst` files distributed in the `.zip` file are all contained in a `bst` folder. These files won't be found inside that folder when you upload everything to Overleaf. Instead, what you need to do is upload the specific `.bst` file you need directly into your project folder. Then it will be found correctly.