# Springer Nature References Overleaf file

Tags: springernature, springer

I want to make the references of my paper as this here: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/springer-nature-latex-template/myxmhdsbzkyd … What should I do? Because I tried uploading the .bib file as a .zip in Overleaf but nothing works... I tried this: [Template of Springer Nature’s LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/644591/template-of-springer-nature-s-latex) nothing works...Any help?

**UPDATE:** How can I put more than 13 References (which is the number of the references the example `sn-bibliography.bib` includes)? I have put `@article{bib14,...` but I don't see something in the compiled document...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I'm afraid a remark such as "nothing works" isn't actionable. Does your LaTeX file start with `\documentclass[sn-nature]{sn-jnl}`?

Comment: In **sn-article.tex** I see this: ```\documentclass[sn-mathphys,Numbered]{sn-jnl}``` The .zip includes many files....

Comment: you need to give some information if you want help. what error message do you get.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you can upload a new project as a zip file, but if you are adding individual new files to an existing project you can't zip  so "I tried uploading the .bib file as a .zip in Overleaf" sounds wrong. You should upload `.bib` files as they are, not as a zip archive.

Comment: Ok, in .bib file I follow this format: ```%% Journal article
@article{bib1,
  author  = "Campbell, S. L. and Gear, C. W.",
  title   = "The index of general nonlinear {D}{A}{E}{S}",
  journal  = "Numer. {M}ath.",
  volume  = "72",
  number  = "2",
  pages   = "173--196",
  year   = "1995"
}``` ?? Is there any faster way?

Comment: don't put code in comments, as you see they are very hard to read. But what does "faster" mean???? your question says something did not work, so what did you do and what error did you get? your fragment looks like a standard bib entry that you would reference  as `\cite{bib1}`  (obviously a bad name it would be better to replace `bib1` by ``cambellgear` or some such, but latex does not care

Comment: I removed the .bib zipped file and I uploaded the whole file from the begining. Then I put ```\documentclass[sn-nature]{sn-jnl}```. As I understand everything I put inside the ```sn-bibliography.bib``` it is depicted in the compiled pdf. Right?? As far as the "faster" is concerned, I mean to copy paste the citation from google scholar (such as HArvard format) and make it Latex with some faster way. I have a lot of References... it is very time consuming to do this with my previously posted message format....

Comment: Ok, this i a nightmare... I managed to do the following "word2latex and latex2word by using textutil with Pandoc" in my mac (source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46015/converting-ms-word-doc-to-latex-by-command-line via this command: ```$ textutil -convert html worddoc.docx -stdout | pandoc -s -f html -t latex -o latexdoc.tex``` and  get a .tex file. I uploaded in Overleaf but it cannot open it...What should I do?

Comment: Please see my update in my initial post...

Comment: Does anyone read the updated question? Thanks...